# Issue in simple program with variables/parameters

Tags: java, variables

I am writing a simple program for fun.  I am new to programming, and am not sure how to fix this problem. The problem is in the printWord method.  Not sure what to put in the parentheses to make it work.  Having Word, does not work.  Here's my code:`public class getWord {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    getWordFromUser("Enter a random word!");
    printWord(Word);
}

/**
 * gets a Word From the User
 */
     public static String getWordFromUser(String prompt){
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println(prompt);
     return sc.nextLine();
  }
/**
 * Prints the random word that the user has entered
 * @param Word 
 */
     public static void printWord(String Word){
         System.out.println("The word you have entered is " + Word);
     }
```

}

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You made a method call `(getWordFromUser())` which returns a string, but you never assigned it to a variable.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You never said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not capturing the return result from the `getWordFromUser` method call.

You can do that in one of two ways:

```
String word = getWordFromUser("Enter a random word!");
printWord(word);
```

...or...

```
printWord(getWordFromUser("Enter a random word!"));
```

Take careful note of the first approach.  I declare a variable `word` to store the value in.  You declare a variable `Word` to reference, but there's no declaration of it anywhere.

Comment: Thanks! I used the first method, works perfect now.  Plan to use this in future programs.